# Eigenspace of a matrix with real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a positive definite diagonal matrix and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix. We know $DA$ has real eigenvalues because $DA=D^{0.5}(D^{0.5}AD^{0.5})D^{-0.5}$. Therefore, $DA$ is similar to $B:=D^{0.5}AD^{0.5}$, which is a symmetric matrix.

I was wondering if the eigenvectors of matrix $DA$ are mutually orthogonal (as this is the case for a symmetric matrix)?

Comment: How do you define $D^{0.5}$?  What if $D = -I$?

Comment: Maybe you should define $D$ as positive definite, otherwise the square root does not necessarily have to exist.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, $D$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$DA$ has not necessarily mutually orthogonal eigenvectors. Take for example

$$D= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then

$$DA = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues of $DA$ are $0$ and $3$ and two corresponding eigenvectors are $v = (1, 1)$ and $w = (-2, 1)$, so $v$ and $w$ are not orthogonal.

Note that the statement can be easily proven to be true if, for example, $D$ and $A$ commute.